# Javascript replace with part of match?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking over `replace()` examples and I'm not exactly sure the best way to do this:

Say I have a string something like

```
{G}{J}{L}...
```

What's the best way to use `string.replace()` to change the inner and outer brackets but leave the letter inside them? Do I need to do separate matches for the outer and inner brackets or is it possible/faster to do it in a single statement?

I see that `$` can get the whole match and I guess I could remove the first and last characters and replace them after but that seems slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "inner and outer brackets"?

Comment: The braces {}. Left and right is better terminology perhaps? All pairs.

Comment: @Glem: Yes. Better terminology would be "opening" and "closing". Inner/outer you will find only when nesting pairs…

Answer (score 3):

```
> "{G}{J}{L}".replace(/{(.)}/g,"$1")
"GJL"
```

Is this what you're after? Or maybe this?

```
> "{G}{J}{L}".replace(/{(.)}/g,"[$1]")
"[G][J][L]"
```

Comment: Something more along the lines of replacing them with new characters, like <G><J><L>. Would this just be "<" + $1 + ">"

Answer (score 0):

One pretty straightforward way is to just perform the replacements separately, and the performance difference should be negligible unless your strings are huge:

```
var string = "{G}{J}{L}";
string = string.replace(/\{/g, "<").replace(/}/g, ">")
```